# Spring Boot - Data Initialization with ddl-auto=update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Simple Spring Boot Web Application with MySQL database and Hibernate as JPA.
I am using Spring Boot Version 2.0.3.

I wish the tables to be auto created and auto populated with initial data.
To achieve this, I have done the below things:
1. Marked by POJO with @Entity
2. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in application.properties
3. data.sql under resources folder
4. spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always in application.properties(As I am not using the embedded H2 database. I am using MySQL Database)

Result:
The table is created and the initial data from data.sql is also loaded successfully. But, when I start my Spring Boot Application again, I get the below exception:

**My doubt is: Why ddl-auto=update is trying to insert the records present in data.sql each time the application starts instead of updating the same?**

```
        Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-03 12:40:49.597 ERROR 26552 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/home/user/Sidhartha/DCT/codebase/trunk-new2/MNS/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.mns.MNS.MnsApplication.main(MnsApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/home/user/Sidhartha/DCT/codebase/trunk-new2/MNS/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/home/user/Sidhartha/DCT/codebase/trunk-new2/MNS/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:589) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:392) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e57cffcc.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.addInterceptors(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:245) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:88) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addInterceptors(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:330) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:282) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:487) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$72f4354.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$2(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$72f4354$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c99e422b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$72f4354.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/home/user/Sidhartha/DCT/codebase/trunk-new2/MNS/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1184) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:120) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:154) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1730) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/home/user/Sidhartha/DCT/codebase/trunk-new2/MNS/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899'); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:494) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:240) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:210) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:79) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:70) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:439) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1850) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2440) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Below are the files:

application.properties

server.port=8001

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AccountServices
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root123

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (1, '9538943899');
INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (2, '9903941332');
INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (3, '8888888888');
INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (4, '7766526318');
INSERT INTO `AccountServices`.`mobile_number` (`id`, `number`) VALUES (5, '9590534687');
```

Entity Class:

```
package com.example.mns.MNS;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MobileNumber
{
    private int id;
    private String number;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.mns</groupId>
    <artifactId>MNS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MNS</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: The problem is caused by your sql file, `data.sql` where you are trying to insert an existing `idìn the table account. You need to edit your script and make sure the table is empty at initialisation time otherwise just the script once. And spring boot will automatically run the script everytime your app is started.

Comment: Error states that requestMapping bean creation issue. Please check if your requestMapping annotation on controller classes is set in the correct way.  

Instead of using hibernate capability for DDL and DML statements, you can prefer to use **liquibase or flyway**.

Comment: @chŝdk I can definitely edit my script to meet my requirements. But my question is: Isn't "update" meant to update the existing data? Why it is trying to insert the same data twice?

Comment: @SidharthaShankar  **No**, update isn't meant to update data, it's meant to update tables structures, columns and relationships in the database, and not the data content.

Comment: @chŝdk Thanks for the answer. You have cleared my doubt about update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way spring works. By using:

> spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

This actually means run data.sql every time you run the application. So you have a couple of options here. One is to disable that initialization and do it manually but it's not a real answer. So you can either:

1. Set

> spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

and this way it will continue the execution after the error.

2. (the better option) Write the SQL idempotent - make it so it can work even if executed multiple times. It can either checks if the data is present and then add the values only if not. Or delete the records with that IDs and then re-insert them. It will still cause some overload at startup which leads to option 3.
3. Use some tool like liquibase that supports DATABASECHANGELOG table and keeps track of which sql change logs have already been executed.

Comment: I was expecting "ddl-auto=update" to update existing rows in my table. But, as pointed out by @chŝdk, it's meant to update tables structures, columns and relationships in the database.
Now, for my application to work, I have changed my SQL script from "INSERT.." to "INSERT IGNORE.."
Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to insert `id = 1` which is already present in table.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Also change this in your code so that everytime the id column is Auto Incremented by SpringBoot App

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
```

Comment: yeah but if he empties the values then he will delete everything in the database? Each restart will clear the mysql table which will is probably not the required behavior

Comment: Sorry i corrected my answer. Thank you @VeselinDavidov

Answer (score 0):

If you use postgres, add

```
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

after INSERT statement. example:

```
INSERT INTO language (id, lang, abbrv, current, rtl)
VALUES (1, 'English', 'en', false, false)      
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```